# Should gRPC health checking be limited to gRPC services?

Tags: grpc, kubernetes-health-check

With regards to [gRPC Health Checking](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md), if a gRPC service is hosted on the same port as other HTTP services that also need health checking, should the responses to `grpc.health.v1.Health.Check` be only for gRPC services provided, or is it reasonable to also answer about other services as well? If the latter, what model for service names should be used?

I ask in part because there's already a [`/healthz` model for Kubernetes health checking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) and am trying to figure out whether we need to provide a ligature to the gRPC health checking, or could convolve the existing health checking, e.g.,

```
import "google.api.http";
…
rpc Check(HealthCheckRequest) returns (HealthCheckResponse) {
  option (google.api.http) = { get: "/healthz" }
}
```

such that the stock gRPC health check monitor could be so used.

Answer (score 1):

gRPC health check shares fate with gRPC server because it is a gRPC method by itself. If the gRPC server outlives or shares fate with your other services, then I think it is ok to use gRPC health checking service to serve the status of other services.

I am not aware of official support for sharing a port between gRPC server and other servers in C++, Java or Go. I am not sure what setup you are thinking, but the general idea above applies.